# How to retain original value on cell edit of datagridview column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having a grid which shows list of products with following columns :

```
ProductId,ProductName,MRP,FinalAmount
```

Now I have kept MRP as editable so that user can change it based on discount on some products.I have kept validation on MRP column to not allow user to enter `null value` but the problem is when I raised the validation message **original MRP value is LOST**.

So what I am trying to do is when user enter negative/null value then I want to show message and retain last MRP value.

**Code :**

```
private void grdProductList_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                if (grdProductList.CurrentCell == null ||
                            grdProductList.CurrentCell.Value == null ||
                            e.RowIndex == -1) return;

                if (grdProductList.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(3))//MRP
                {
                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(grdProductList.Rows[grdProductList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["MRP"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("MRP cannot be empty.Please provide value", "Error");
                        return;
                    }

                    decimal.TryParse(grdProductList.Rows[grdProductList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["MRP"].Value.ToString(), out decimal mrp);
                    if(mrp < 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("MRP cannot have negative value", "Error");
                        return;
                    }
                    grdProductList.Rows[grdProductList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["FinalAmount"].Value = mrp;
                    //calculation code based on mrp
                }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the **MRP** original value in a temp variable,
 if user entered null or negative value, restore the temp value to current grid cell

Comment: But when I receive user entered value inside CellEndEdit event and not original value.Question is How do i get original mrp value inside that event

Answer (score 0):

I have found that DataGridView provides a method called [CancelEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.canceledit(v=vs.110).aspx) which discards the changes and also helps to retain original value.

I just need to call this method like below and got the expected behaviour :

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(grdProductList.Rows[grdProductList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["MRP"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("MRP cannot be empty.Please provide value", "Error");
                        grdProductList.CancelEdit();
                        return;
                }
```